# In operator on array returns incorrect result

Tags: javascript

I have this code.

```
var myArr = ["bar", "baz", 'snuff'];
myArr[2];
console.log("2" in myArr);
```

It says `true`.
I am confused. The `2` is not in myArr So how come it's `**true**`

Comment: `in` works on **keys** ~ `index` in array.

Comment: @Ok so 2 is changed to int and 2 here means index??

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini Array indexes create properties. `'snuff'` creates this property.

Comment: so 2 is changed to int and 2 here means index??

Comment: The `index` is stored as **string** internally, so there is no need of casting to `string`.

Comment: @Thushar thanks but i wanted to know that it here means we have a vaue in 2nd index right> i mean 2 in myArr?

Comment: @MarcAndreJiacarrini It just checks if there is an index in the array, it has nothing to do with the value at that index.